# what is the use of Repository in Mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I had created the  three layer architecture i.e. Data Access Layer ,Business Logic and Web Layer (UI).In BL Layer ,I am using the directly the context class which is created in the DAL Layer .

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty helpful article on why, and how to use repositories in MVC.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/631668/Learning-MVC-Part-Repository-Pattern-in-MVC-App

Repositories are basically used as a layer between the data access layer and your business logic.